# get Notified when a python script run

Tags: python

I want to know if there is somehow I can know Every time my script is run like an email but the problem with email is I have to authorize it first but I want something that doesn't needs authorization it can be anything. I don't even know if its possible but thanks for the help :)

```
smtpServer='smtp.yourdomain.com'      
fromAddr='from@Address.com'         
toAddr='to@Address.com'     
text= "This is a test of sending email from within Python."
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer,25)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.sendmail(fromAddr, toAddr, text) 
server.quit()
```

this gives authentication requires error

Comment: Using a log? The [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) package gives you some nice options. Write down every time your script starts (append, not overwrite) and you know every time it runs. Could this work?

Comment: yes  it could work. can you give me a snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is very simple, just import the logging module

```
import logging
```

Set up the logger (telling him the file where to log and the format)

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
```

In this case it will create a logfile.log in the root folder, and write always the time [explanation here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#displaying-the-date-time-in-messages)

And then every time you need to print, use

```
logging.info('print something')
```

And it will be printed on the log with the date and time.
You can of course [print variable data](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-variable-data) if needed.

From the logging module, a simple example:

```
# import the log
import logging

def setupLog():
    # set up 
    logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    # adding format='%(asctime)s %(message)s' 
    # will add the time to your log messages
    logging.info('Starting to write in the log')

def myScript():
    logging.info('Starting my script..')
    # do whatever your script does
    logging.info('Finishing my script..')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setupLog()
    myscript()
```

Comment: how to I attach that log to emails without authorizing my email